# How to test belonging of value to distribution defined by set of samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a set of $\{X_i\}^N_1$ observations. Under assumption that they all come from unknown distribution $D$, what is the statistical test for observation $Y$ (one value) to belong to the same distribution?